# undefined method `each' in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried the same scenario in `rails console`

But why am I getting...

undefined method `each` for `#<ProjectProcurementManagementPlan:0x007ff9ecda2148>`

In my model, I have a callback that will update the form immediately

```
after_update :check_app_on_update?

def check_app_on_update?

      self.each do |ppmp|
        ppmp_year = ppmp.year
        get_app = AnnualProcurementPlan.where(year: ppmp_year)
        get_id = get_app.map{|a| a.id }
        get_id.each do |app_id|
          update_attribute(:annual_procurement_plan_id, app_id)
        end
      end  
    end
```

But keeps on getting `undefined method 'each'`

But whenever I remove the `self.each` loop...

I get `'stack level too deep'` type of error.

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Okay, now i realize that I should stick to my old approach. And that is without `each`

```
def check_app_on_update?
      ppmp_year = self.year
      get_app = AnnualProcurementPlan.where(year: ppmp_year)
      get_id = get_app.map{|a| a.id }

      get_id.each do |app_id|
        # ppmp = ProjectProcurementManagementPlan.last    
        #         ppmp.update_attribute(:annual_procurement_plan_id, app_id )
        @idd = app_id
      end
        update_attribute(:annual_procurement_plan_id, @idd )
  end
```

But i am getting `stack level too deep` error

I saw from the logs, that there's an endless loop.

```
(0.5ms)  UPDATE "project_procurement_management_plans" SET "status" = 'Approved', "updated_at" = '2013-05-31 09:55:00.000000', "annual_procurement_plan_id" = 1 WHERE "project_procurement_management_plans"."id" = 19
  AnnualProcurementPlan Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "annual_procurement_plans".* FROM "annual_procurement_plans" WHERE "annual_procurement_plans"."year" = 2012
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16737ms

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70:in `'
```

Comment: What do you want to check exactly? The object that was just updated? Or other records?

Comment: The object that is being updated

Comment: So you want to loop through its attributes? Or just a particular one?

Comment: @SergeyBolgov has the answer ;)

Comment: It'll help if you describe what you trying to do here. there is multiple solutions for a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `self` means 1 object and there is no `.each` method for 1 object, `.each` is for collections.

Comment: Thanks but how about the `stack level too deep`

Comment: Please post that as a separate question, questions that have multiple sub-question's don't fit well, usually the title doesn't work or 'both', etc.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is:

`stack level too deep` occurs because `update_attribute()` calls `check_app_on_update?` again that calls `update_attribute()` that calls `check_app_on_update?` again ...

Need more information to be more confident ...

Comment: @xirukitepe Try to add debug prints: one at the beginning of the method and one before `update_attribute` call. If you will see a sequence of prints, then my guess is true. At this case, you should not call `update_attribute` from `check_app_on_update?` because that introduces infinite recursion.